# Variables are not passed from one script calling another with Bash heredoc

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell-script

I have a shell script kept at my local user called (`executeAdM.sh`), and when I execute this script I am switching to a sudo user by taking commands from an instruction file. But when I execute this script I am also passing parameters, which is actually some directory path of the sudo user. See the script below.

Script for local user (`executeADM.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo password | sudo -S -l
sudo /usr/bin/su - user  <<\EOF
#ls -lrt
pwd
for entry in $(ls -r)
  do
  if [ "$entry" = "testingADM.sh" ];then
    ./"$entry" "$1"
  fi
done
EOF
```

I'm executing the above as:

```
./executeADM.sh "/global/u70/globe/ADM"
```

When the above script executes, it switches successfully to the other user, and with the sudo user I execute a `for` loop which searches for another script called `testingADM.sh`.

Once the script is found I execute that script with the parameter passed from the local user, and `testingADM.sh` should set the path for me.

This is not working – it is not reading the parameter passed from the local user.

The sudo user script (`testingADM.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
changepath=$1
cd "$changepath"
pwd
```

When I hardcode the path variable in the script, all works fine. But I don't want that:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 changepath=somepath
 cd "$changepath"
 pwd
```

The issue is instead of going to `"/global/u70/globe/ADM"` it takes the path as `"/global/u70/globe/"`, Which is the path after I do `sudo`. It is just not passing the variable.

---

With the below suggestions, this is what I ended up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo password | sudo -S -l
sudo /usr/bin/su - user  <<EOF
#ls -lrt
#pwd
echo "$1"
./testingADM.sh "$1"
EOF
```

The `echo` command prints nothing; a blank space is shown. It worked when I changed `\EOF` to `EOF`.

Can anyone explain the difference between:

```
\EOF , "EOF" , 'EOF' , EOF
```

or do the first three have the same meaning? Then what is difference between them?

Comment: Please don't change your question after you received an answer that solves your problem. Once a question is answered, it's confusing if it gets changed or has additions later. If you have further questions, it's better to solve them in the comments or ask an entirely new question.

Comment: @slhck got your point so now can you tell me the reason in comment section?

Comment: I'm not sure I can answer this without some specific examples, seeing what you've tried and why it didn't work for you. So please ask a new question about it. Thanks!

Comment: Okk no issues i will post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not quote or escape your heredoc limit string (i.e. use `EOF` instead of `\EOF` or `"EOF"`), as otherwise, special variables like `$` will not be interpreted. See [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) for more info and examples (e.g. Example 19-7).

Here is a minimal script that works:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo su - $(whoami) <<EOF
./test2.sh "$1"
EOF

$ cat test2.sh
#!/bin/bash
foo=$1
echo "$foo"

$ ./test1.sh "/path/to/file"
"/path/to/file"
```

Note that:

- There is no need for the heredoc at all. Just call `./test2.sh` directly after `sudo`: `sudo -u $(whoami) test2.sh "$1"`
- [You should not loop over the output of `ls`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- There is no need to do a `for` loop to search for a single file. Just call the script directly with its name.

You should also quote your variables, that is:

- Execute your script with `./executeADM.sh "/path/with white/space"`
- Call `./"$entry" "$1"` in your script
- In your other script, use `cd "$path"`

In general:

- Always double-quote variables. (Don't single-quote them -- they won't expand.)
- Don't use a variable called `path`. (Much as you wouldn't use variables called `user`, `home`, etc.)

Comment: i updated my answer with path i am providing.

Comment: So when you `echo "$changepath"`, it is `/global/u70/globe/` and not `/global/u70/globe/ADM`? That's quite strange.

Comment: @slhck: that is weird, indeed.

Comment: @slhck exactly mate is it due to passing parameter from local and reading after sudo with EOF? May be it is not sending parameter ??

Comment: @tukan yes indeed it is , and i think EOF is not reading parameter.

Comment: @TusharSharma: if you do try to start is without variable having it first in variable like: ./testingADM.sh "$1" does it work?

Comment: @tukan you mean if i execute without for loop?

Comment: @TusharSharma: yes no loop, no if.

Comment: @tukan let me give a try.Will let you know

Comment: @TusharSharma If you get the variable transferred (which has nothing to do with EOF; this is fine), then the loop also does not really have an impact.  Your problem seems to be that the output is not what you passed to it, which to me means that there is something else going on in your script (e.g. code that you are not showing here). If you reduce this to the simplest possible use case, does it work? (See my answer)

Comment: @slhck updated code.

Comment: @tukan updated code.

Comment: @slhck ok gr8 it worked if i changed \EOF to EOF but why.?

Comment: @TusharSharma Quoting or escaping EOF (the heredoc delimiter) disables variable expansion inside. I first didn't notice that you did that when I typed my example. See my answer for an update with a link to an explanation.

Comment: @slhck thanks for helping and giving your time . Thanks a lot sir i will read that document.

Comment: @TusharSharma You're welcome. I edited the question for clarity.

Comment: @slhck no issues sir.

Comment: @slhck I checked your updated answer ,and as you mentioned no need to use here doc. I am just using it to take instructions after sudo, earlier when I tried to do without it commands get executed in local user only.

Comment: @slhck sorry sir i by mistake edited your code instead of mine.I corrected that.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**
From back of my head.  Does your path contain spaces?

If yes you need to execute it as `./executeADM.sh 'somePath'`.

It is always better to save the `$1` into a variable when you are passing it further it makes it easier to read.  I would add `path=$1` then in batch file you would have `./$entry "$path"`

Comment: `./$entry '$path'` will not expand the variable but pass it literally as `$path`.

Comment: @slhck: you are right.  I've edited the answer to have double quotes - for expansions.  The first path can be with single quotes there you don't need any expansion.

Comment: Although as you can see in the OP's update to the question, that is not the problem.

Comment: @slhck: ah missed that, will check it out. Thanks for the update.

Comment: @tukan thanks for your help and time as well sorry I responded late.

Comment: @TusharSharma: No worries.  I'm glad you solved your problem :).  I have overlooked the EOF then it became clear.